# Formula to Apply Filter on Excel Table

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets in an Excel 2013 workbook. The first has a table of client information and the second is a table of purchases by client. The second table has the "Client ID" tied to each purchase. What I would like to achieve is a link next to each client in the clients table that when clicked sends a user to a filtered view of the purchases in the second table. I believe I can use Excels hyperlink capabilities to link across worksheets, but how would I make it apply a filter to a table?

Many thanks!

K.

Comment: It's ok to use VBA or not ?

Comment: If it works/is stable, I'm open to it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Scheme. **Link Sheet [Sheet...]**:

[image]

and **Data Sheet [Data]**:

[image]

you can add the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Crit As String

    If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
         If Target.Column = 3 Then
            Crit = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
            If ActiveCell.Row = 1 Then Crit = "ALL"
            If Crit = "" Then Exit Sub

            Sheets("Data").Select
            Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
            If Crit = "ALL" Then ' ALL
                Selection.AutoFilter
            Else
                Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Crit
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the event selection Change of the Sheet with the list of the names.
The macro consider the Data are on the Sheet "Data".
If you click on the label **ALL** the macro show all ...

Comment: Follow up question. What I need my table to start a few rows down to allow for a heading in rows 1 and 2 (ex. Row One = Client List, Row Two = Date)

Comment: Never mind. I just need to start the range at A3 (ex. Sheets("Data").Range("A3").Select)